# What services accept tcp connection?

Tags: fedora, services, telnet, xinetd, inetd

I've been learning about socket programming recently, and am just beginning learning about tcp/ip sockets. [My study material](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=62.html) gives an example of connecting to the localhost `daytime` service by running `telnet 127.0.0.1 13` with the expected result that a telnet session should be opened. I have an entry for "`daytime 13/tcp`" in my `/etc/services` file, and I have the `xinetd` service running, but when I try the telnet command, I immediately get "Connection refused".

**Q**: why doesn't telnetting to the daytime service work?

**Q**: are there other localhost services that would accept a telnet connection? I tried to telnet to a random selection of services that had `tcp` entries in `/etc/services`, but all of them gave the same "Connection refused" error.

My short-term goal is just to replicate my study material's successful telnet connection to a localhost tcp service - if not `inetd`, then anything else; I just want to learn by practice.

```
>telnet 127.0.0.1 13
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
>telnet 127.0.0.1 49000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
>telnet 127.0.0.1 9009
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
>uname -a
Linux linuxbox 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you can't telnet locally to the specified ports such as 13, 49000, etc. that only means the ports aren't open in iptables..

Comment: @ryekayo Well, and also no service is running on those ports.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/etc/services` does not indicate what services are actually running. See [purpose of /etc/services](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-etc-services-2196940). You will need to find a service that is running (or start one). You can see what is listening by looking at `netstat -nlt`. The particular services will vary, but you will see something like:

```
$ netstat -nlt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

So:

1. `daytime` service is probably not running. If it does not appear in the list (and you can see from the listing above I do not have it running), then nothing is listening on the port. It may be possible to start the service if it is installed.
2. There are lots of other potential services depending upon what is installed and active. In the listing above, port `25` is listening, which is the mail service. So I could connect via `telnet` to port 25. As telnet is not installed by default, I use `nc` to connect, but the principle is the same:

   `$ nc 127.0.0.1 25
   220 centos7.feedthecoder.com ESMTP Postfix
   HELO me.theworld.com
   ...`

Edit: as mentioned in a comment, it could of course be a firewall issue. Generally installations do not block `127.0.0.1`, but it is always a possibility.

Also, depending upon your distribution, `daytime` may not be installed, which would be a further impediment. If it is installed, <s>you should be able to start it via the normal service start (e.g., `service start daytime`, or the distro equivalent).</s>

Edit: it turns out that `daytime` is provided solely by `xinetd` as an internal service. So while the information above about listing services is correct, to have `daytime`, ensure that `xinetd` is installed, and that the file `/etc/xinetd/daytime-stream` has `disabled` set to `no`.

Comment: Confirming: I could reproduce your examples, and was able to `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`. You are correct: daytime appears to not be running. There's some relationship between `inetd` and `daytime` I don't fully understand yet. I thought because the former was running meant the latter was as well. But I guess that's a separate question to follow shortly. :)