# How do I launch the daytime service?

Tags: fedora, systemd, services, xinetd

Whenever I think I'm getting comfortable with Linux, I get stumped by a simple problem that exposes my inexperience: how do I launch the `daytime` service? My trail of attempts is as follows:

```
>sudo systemctl start daytime
Failed to issue method call: Unit daytime.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
>which daytime
/usr/bin/which: no daytime in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/utils/:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/utils/:/home/user/utils/:/home/user/utils/:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/utils/)
>locate daytime
/etc/xinetd.d/daytime-dgram
/etc/xinetd.d/daytime-stream
>sudo systemctl start daytime-stream
Failed to issue method call: Unit daytime-stream.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
>systemctl status xinetd
xinetd.service - Xinetd A Powerful Replacement For Inetd
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/xinetd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-06-12 18:10:28 PDT; 16h ago
  Process: 5005 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid $EXTRAOPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5006 (xinetd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xinetd.service
            /usr/sbin/xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
>uname -a
Linux linuxbox 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a very shaky understanding that there is some relationship between `xinetd` and `daytime`, but, e.g., I don't understand if the fact that the `xinetd` service is running means that `daytime` is/should also be running, or if I need to start it independently? If I am supposed to start it independently, then how can I? I'm out of ideas after my above-noted attempts all failed.

Comment: Please try this: edit the file `/etc/xinetd.d/daytime-stream`. In that file, change the line disable from `yes` to `no`. Then do `sudo systemctl restart xinetd`. You will then be able to `telnet 127.0.0.1 13` and get the output.

Comment: @Theophrastus - actually this question is a follow-up to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370920/what-services-accept-tcp-connection . I don't specifically want to achieve NTP time sync; rather I just wanted to achieve a telnet connection to the `daytime` service because some learning material I am studying suggested this was possible.

Comment: @KevinO - Thank you: your recommendation was right on. After following your suggestions, I re-ran `netstat -nlt` and now I saw an entry for `tcp6 0 0 :::13 :::* LISTEN`. After this, I re-ran `telnet 127.0.0.1 13` and at last saw output that matched my study material. I'll add what I learned from this exercise to my bag of tricks - thank you. (You may want to post as an answer if you'd like the reputation points)

Comment: @KevinO - If this is not too off-topic, I'm just curious: do you know why the 'Local Address' field is shown as `:::13` instead of `127.0.0.1:13` ? I see a mix of both styles in the `netstat -nlt` output.

Comment: The `:::13` is IPv6 on the local machine (I don't recall the rules for when one can omit part of the address in IPv6). The other entry `127.0.0.1:###` is for IPv4. IIRC, the `:::13` is indicating an IPv6 binding for for all addresses on port 13. In contrast, you might see `::1:25` which is binding the `smtp` service to localhost on port 25. You can see the `::1` in the `/etc/hosts` file (for localhost).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xinetd` daemon essentially listens for requests and then launches given service for it. [Wikipedia entry for xinetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinetd).

From the OP's question, one can see `/etc/xindet.d/daytime-stream`, which means that `xinetd` is installed, along with the `daytime` service. However, as it is generally recommended for `daytime` to not be enabled [see, e.g., acunetix and security scanning](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/daytime-service-running), it must be specifically enabled. To enable it, edit the file `/etc/xinetd.d/daytime-stream` and change the `disabled` from 'yes' to 'no` (backwards logic is backwards).

After restarting the xinetd via `sudo systemctl xinetd restart` (or equivalent), the `xinetd` daemon will start the service when a request is made on the port. The mapping between the port and the service is defined in `/etc/services` (but may be specified in the relevant xinetd file).

Comment: From the wikipedia article: "`xinetd` listens for incoming requests over a network and launches the appropriate service for that request." Does this mean, e.g. it listens for "telnet requests" and if one arrives, then it launches `telnetd`?

Comment: @StoneThrow, configured correctly, I believe `xinetd` can start the `telnet` or `ssh` daemon, but I do not believe it is the normal use-case (certainly not for `ssh` on modern distributions). Many/most services are started through (now) `systemd`. I think an interesting question you might pose (and which I am not qualified to answer) is the evolution of service starting/monitoring between `xinetd`/sysV init/systemd. `xinetd` wasn't installed by default on my CentOS 7 machine, and I haven't used or configured it in years.